# TypeScript, I can't Omit<someUnion, oneInterface> . why?

Tags: typescript

Please see this minimum example:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}
interface B {
  b: number;
}
interface C {
  c: number;
}

type ABC = A | B | C;

type omitA = Omit<ABC, A>;
```

[image]

I can't Omit an interface, however, omitting a string property works fine.

How can I exclude the interface?

Answer (score 5):

The `Omit` type is for removing **properties** from a type (by providing their name as string, number or symbol).

What you are looking for is `Exclude`, which has been [added in version 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types)

```js
type ABC = A | B | C;

type omitA = Exclude<ABC, A>;
```